# Xero API contact list using summaryOnly removes contacts

Tags: php, xero-api

Issue: When using the **/Contacts?summaryOnly=true** endpoint the payload list does not contain the full list of contacts.

I have a a call that performs a lookup to get all the contacts then use code to partial match the string used to search to the name. Kind if like a %string% in SQL.
I understand there is a 'where' options using the PHP SDK for Xero. I do not use this but may need to fall back.

Using Postman the difference in **/Contacts** vs **/Contacts?summaryOnly=true** is 1MB vs 53KB. Hence I would like to use the summary endpoint. BUT when using the summary the dataset returned does not have all contacts that are in the system.
Is there some undocumented feature that returns a subset of data if summaryOnly is sent as a query parameter?

I'm using the PHP SDK ( https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-php-oauth2 )

Comment: Is this a pagination issue? The doc does say "And when this parameter is used, pagination is enforced by default."

Comment: Correct. Support has also confirmed that when passing the parameter pagination occurs. Seems a bit strange that one may want a full summary and not the full list (just for company names lets say) but for this is seems one needs the full /Contacts list. thanks @droopsnoot

Answer (score 0):

As per @droopsnoot comments and confirmed with Xero support.
Passing the parameter (apparently any query parameter) causes pagination to occur.